# Question about distributions offering certain software labeled as "too broad"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

Can someone please explain why [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247657/are-any-upcoming-distros-offering-php-7-by-default) question of mine was closed as "too broad".  It seems to conform to the site guidelines.  And it is very specific.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, Though the "default" part is crucial, am I right? Without that, the question simply reduces to having PHP 7 in a distribution, and that is usually possible through third party packages and/or backports.

Comment: yes, exactly.  i am asking about distros that plan to include it by **default**, not through 3rd party repo

Comment: Hmm. You wrote "as the default version", which is not the same as "include it by default". The former means that `php` would invoke PHP7. So, which of these do you mean? "as the default version" is possibly significant, while "include it by default is not".

Comment: @FaheemMitha - thanks, i understand how that's more clear and yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Um, so which of those did you mean?

Comment: "the default version" is what I wrote in my original question and that is what I meant.

Comment: Ah, Ok. In that case, the answers to that quesiton are largely besides the point, since including PHP 7 in a distribution does not make it the default. You might want to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't have voted to close it but it feels overly broad to me in the sense that there are a lot of distros that will fall into this category, and that list will change overtime, so there won't be a consistent answer to your question.

The other bit, and you do say "default" so you're trying to restrict the question's broadness, is that who's to say that a 3rd party repo that's well supported, isn't in play when discussing what one would consider as "default".

For example, I'd consider the EPEL repo as "technically" part of the default, even though you have to add it, given it's well maintained and pretty core to most anything you'll want to do on a CentOS distro.

Other distros will vary, but I suspect there are repos similar to this in other distros as well.

Again this is just my $0.02 on this but this question just has a air of broadness that it cuts just too close to the edge, IMO.

Comment: If you look here for instance: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu and scroll down to PHP - it shows the current version 7.0.3, and then in each version column the PHP version that is part of the distribution.  That is what I'm asking about.  So far I haven't one that doesn't require a 3rd party repo and that is what I'm after.  How can I make this more clear in the question?  It may be a non-starter at the moment but I have a feeling as time goes on this question may become more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

> **There are** either **too many possible answers**, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the
>   answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few
>   paragraphs.

At time T1, $RANDOM_DISTRO1 plans to add PHP7 as a default. It's an answer.

At time T2, $RANDOM_DISTRO2 plans to add PHP7 as a default. It's an answer.

At time T3, $RANDOM_DISTRO3 plans to add PHP7 as a default. It's an answer.

...

At some point, most distros will have PHP7 as a default. The question is meaningless.

Comment: Can you give me even one real example of an upcoming release which **you are aware of** that will be including php7?  I didn't ask anyone to hypothesize about theoretical plans.  Looking for concrete news about releases.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php7.0 https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch - make of that what you will. Nobody's hypothesizing.

Comment: And while we're at it: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7.0, and we all know when Ubuntu 16.04 will release. Follow on for *every* distro that's based on Ubuntu and will release a new version based on 16.04.